# por que no me aparece le ado.net entity Data model?

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]hola queria saber por que no me aparece el ado.net entity Data model ya que no me aparece en la lista cuanto quiero agragar

Comment: Puedes decirnos que version de visual studio tienes?

Answer (score 0):

Debes instalar el paquete Entity Framework utilizando NuGet.
Para ello has anda a al menu "Herrarmientas/Administrador de paquetes NuGet/Consola del Administrador de paquetes"
y en la consola escribies el comando

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.2.0
```

mas informacion en https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/

Comment: lo hice aprete enter y reinicie el visual y no pasa nada

Comment: Esto solo instala el EF en el proyecto actual(proyecto que este selecionado en la consola)...  el necesita instarlo como tool o componente del visual studio.  Se puede hacer mediante el Visual Studio Installer

Answer (score 0):

1. Ve al menu Tools(Herramientas) => Click Get Tools and Features(Obtener herramientas y mejoras).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Selecciona  el tab Individual components(Componente individuales) y despues pon el check en Entity Framework 6 tools en la seccion SDK's, libraries, y framework

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]